# Can DAO be used for multiple tables ?

Tags: java, spring, dao

I am in the process of development of small app in javaSE just to make my skills better. So I have business service (BS further) where some methods are like registerUser(User user), addAmount(Long accountId). BS uses dao. Lets assume BS is called  from WS or other interface element. I have following DAOs:

```
public interface UserDao {

    User getUserByUsername(String username);

    void saveUser(User user);
}

public interface AccountDao {

    void saveAccount(Account account);

    Account getAccountByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

My BS looks like

```
public class FastAccountServiceImpl implements FastAccountService{

private UserDao userDao;
private AccountDao accountDao;

public void registerUser(User user, Account account) throws Exception {
    if (user.getUsername() == null || user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("all params are mandatory");
    }
    if (userDao.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
        throw new Exception("This user exists");
    }
    userDao.saveUser(user);
    accountDao.saveAccount(account);
}

public void withdrawAmount(Double amount, Long userId) throws Exception {
    if (amount == null || userId == null) {
        throw new Exception("amount and userId are mandatory");
    }
    Account account = accountDao.getAccountByUserId(userId);
    if (account.getAmount() == null || account.getAmount().compareTo(amount) < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Insufficient amount in account");
    }......

}}
```

So my first question is where should I check params for null etc ? In BS ? 
Second question is why should we have separate dao for every table ? Can I create just one dao for all tables. So in BS there only one dao will be. This dao is represented below:

```
public interface MagicDao {

User getUserByUsername(String username);

void saveUser(User user);

void saveAccount(Account account);

Account getAccountByUserId(Long userId);
```

}

Comment: This may be a better question for StackExchang'es [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) site, but make sure you read their rules and help center to ensure you follow their guidelines.

Comment: @DanielBickler when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat that makes sense... I thought this question would likely be closed as off topic or opinion based so it wouldn't be cross posting. Was that incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes checking for nulls in the business service is better than checking for them in the Dao, since this is a layered architecture and checking in the BS happens earlier.

As for why "one Dao per table" - well, Dao´s have a habit of becoming much more complex over time, so if you have 2 operations on "Account" table right now, in future there could well be 10 or 20 operations, so a cohesive 1-to-1 approach is more manageable and also more easily testable.

So I would certainly avoid `MagicDao`. The job of operating across tables is the role of the service (or some other pattern, like a `Facade`) - not the Dao, at least per common convention.

Besides, modern dependency injection frameworks make it simple to declare and use all the Daos you need in the service. Theres no problem with having 5 or more Daos in a business service (one per table) - I see that quite commonly in code that I work with.

By the way you could use `IllegalArgumentException` in the places where you are throwing `Exception` - its more explicit and its also a `RuntimeException` (so you don't need to declare it with `throws`)

Comment: One can use hibernate validator also in JavaSE https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/using-hibernate-bean-validator-in-java-se.html

Comment: @vikingsteve , thanks a lot. What's the name of service which goes across tables ? Why do we need dao and when do we use it ?

Comment: `FastAccountServiceImpl` is a perfect example of a service that goes across tables. We use a Dao (Data Access Object) as a layer of abstraction to separate the "database code" from the "service code", thereby reducing complexity in your service class and promoting code reusablity (other service classes can use the same Dao´s).

Comment: "The job of operating across tables is the role of the service". No, in the service layer you don't write queries. You write them in the data access layer. A complex query touch more tables. Now the question is: from my service layer can I reference this DAO class that will touch multiple tables?